# How to check if all characters of string are supported from custom font in android

Tags: android, fonts, android-edittext, textview

I am using some custom fonts files in my android app. However they do not support some special characters or other letters than latin. How can i check if a passed string includes any characters that are not supported from my custom font? i saw similar question which mainly focus on the emoji support and rendering.